# How do i fix axesubplot object is not subscriptable error

Tags: python

i dont know how to fix this code. I tried so much but nothing works. Maybe my brain is just overworked right now but maybe you can help.

I would really appreciate it. Thanks!

```
display_price_variation_graph(stocks,start,end,stocks_list):

new_stocks = {}
for key in stocks:
    new_stocks[key] = {'Date':'','Open':'','Close':'','Difference':''}
for key in stocks:
    data = stocks[key]
    data = data.reset_index()
    data.columns = ['Date', *data.columns[1:]]
    new_stocks[key]['Date'] = data['Date']
    new_stocks[key]['Close'] = data['Close']
    new_stocks[key]['Open'] = data['Open']
for key in new_stocks:
    close_price = new_stocks[key]['Close'].tolist()
    open_price = new_stocks[key]['Open'].tolist()
    new_stocks[key]['Difference'] = final_list = [a - b for a, b in zip(open_price, close_price)]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(stocks_list))

colors = ['orange','green','red','blue']
count = 0
for key in new_stocks:
    i = random.randint(0,len(colors)-1)
    axs[count].plot(new_stocks[key]['Date'], new_stocks[key]['Difference'],label=key,color=colors[i])
    axs[count].legend(loc='upper left')
    count += 1

fig.suptitle(f'Price Variation From {start} to {end}')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I think I know what the error is, but I need to understand what you want to do: are you trying to plot multiple figures or multiple data on the same figure?

Comment: Hey 
i want to plot multiple figures:

I tried to create a figure where you see what price changes specif shares had gone through. (opening price - closing price)

Comment: I thought the error was in `fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(stocks_list))`
(I've never done it like that). But as it is, your code should work. Just make sure `stocks_list` has more than one element. I imagine this is causing the error.

Comment: Is it uncommon / bad to use it like that? how would you have used it here?

Comment: It's very commom, actually. The fact is that I almost never define just the `nrows` parameter, so I got used to always specifying (`nrows` and `ncols`) it when I'm going to create multiple figures. The "missing" `nrows` in your code was the first thing that caught my attention, but it's not wrong.